# select one row from many with same id

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I cant figure out how to do this.
I need to select only one row for unique name where mod_date is the latest value

```
mod_date      smtn           name     smtn2

2013-01-31  LV002002310453   Rax      zse
2013-01-29  LV002002310453   Rax      zse         
2013-01-31  LV002002310463   Rendo    xxc           
2013-01-01  LV002002310463   Rendo    xxc          
2013-01-28  LV002002310465   Mag      xsa        
2013-01-30  LV002002310465   Mag      xsa     
2013-01-25  LV002002310465   Mag      xsa
```

my select result should look like :

```
 mod_date      smtn          name     smtn2

2013-01-31  LV002002310453   Rax       zse
2013-01-31  LV002002310463   Rendo     xxc       
2013-01-30  LV002002310465   Mag       xsa
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` in a CTE (assuming >= SQL-SERVER 2005)

```
WITH x AS (SELECT mod_date,smtn,name,smtn2, 
                RN = Row_number() 
                       OVER( 
                         partition BY name 
                         ORDER BY mod_date DESC) 
         FROM   dbo.tablename) 
SELECT mod_date,smtn,name,smtn2 
FROM   x 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Use `DENSE_RANK` instead if you want all rows when the last date for a name is not unique.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
select * From
(
    select 
        Row_number() over (partition by name order by mod_date desc) RNUM, 
        mod_date, 
        name
    From 
        YourTable
)x where RNUM=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select distinct smtn from Databasename order by mod_date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Using distinct can probably omit duplicate data, but can also conflict, since it can also omit useful data.

You can just order by your result (on basis of date) so that you can sort it on basis of date.

**select * from (tablename) order by [Date] desc**